# What will happen when I use an invalid pin number?

Tags: programming

> Related to:
>   [What happens if there is a runtime error?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/189/what-happens-if-there-is-a-runtime-error)

This question is similar to the one above, however this is an alternate situation:

```
int pin = 999;
pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
```

What would happen in this instance? The compiler might catch it but if you used a random number would the IDE catch it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler will not detect any error and the code will compile and execute. Hence, to see what happens we need to explore the behind-the-scenes magic. *For a summary, skip to end.*

---

The second line in your code is where the magic will happen and thats where we need to focus.

```
pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
```

The portion of `pinMode` relevant to this discussion is:

```
void pinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode) 
{

    uint8_t bit = digitalPinToBitMask(pin); //The first instance where pin is used
    uint8_t port = digitalPinToPort(pin);

    if (port == NOT_A_PIN) return;

//Do something
}
```

(The complete implementation can be found in [wiring_digital.c](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c))

So, here, `digitalPinToBitMask` seems to be using `pin` to compute an intermediate bit. Exploring further, `digitalPinToBitMask` is a macro defined in [`Arduino.h`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/cc6d7cdbd1f97aa90ffcb759b5fc4c5ba553304e/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h) whose definition is this one-liner:

```
#define digitalPinToBitMask(P) ( pgm_read_byte( digital_pin_to_bit_mask_PGM + (P) ) )
```

This weird looking one liner does a very simple task. It indexes the P<sup>th</sup> element in the array `digital_pin_to_bit_mask_PGM` and returns it. This array `digital_pin_to_bit_mask_PGM` is defined in [`pins_arduino.h`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/2a8c06381fbc6fdb7e6363d0cb5d1c16019ccab0/hardware/arduino/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h) or the pin map for the specific board being used.

```
const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_bit_mask_PGM[] = {
    _BV(0), /* 0, port D */
    _BV(1),
    _BV(2),
    _BV(3),
    _BV(4),
    _BV(5),
    _BV(6),
    _BV(7),
...
};
```

This array has 20 elements in total, so we are out of luck. 999 will index a memory location in the flash memory outside of this array, thereby leading to unpredictable behavior. *Or will it?*

We still have another line of defense against runtime anarchy. Its the next line of the function `pinMode`:

```
uint8_t port = digitalPinToPort(pin);
```

`digitalPinToPort` takes us along a similar path. It is defined as a macro along with `digitalPinToBitMask`. Its definition is:

```
#define digitalPinToPort(P) ( pgm_read_byte( digital_pin_to_port_PGM + (P) ) )
```

Now, we index the P<sup>th</sup> element of `digital_pin_to_port_PGM` which is an array defined in the pin map:

```
const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_port_PGM[] = {
    PD, /* 0 */
    PD,
    ....
    PC,
    PC,
};
```

This array contains 20 elements, so 999 is again out of range. Again, this command reads and returns a value from flash memory of whose value we cannot be certain. This will again lead to unpredictable behavior from here on.

There is still one last line of defense. That is the `if` check in `pinMode` on the return value of `digitalPinToPort`:

```
if (port == NOT_A_PIN) return;
```

`NOT_A_PIN` is defined as 0 in `Arduino.h`. So, if the returned byte from `digitalPinToPort` happens to be zero, then `pinMode` will silently fail and return.

In any case, `pinMode` cannot save us from anarchy. 999 is destined to result in doom.

---

**TL;DR, the code will execute and the result of this will be unpredictable.** Most likely, no pin will be set to `OUTPUT`, and `digitalWrite` will fail. If you happen to have exceptionally bad luck, then a random pin may get set to `OUTPUT`, and `digitalWrite` may set it to `HIGH`.

Comment: It's interesting there is no bounds checking. digitalWrite is so slow and bulky anyway, it wouldn't be awkward to put in either compile time or run time checks.

Comment: If all arduino pins are in a contiguous range, than couldn't they replace the port==not a pin check with a pin>BOARD_MAX_PIN check, where board max pin is defined in some header file based on some ifdef that detects the board?

Comment: You are forgetting that 999 cannot be represented in a `uint8_t` so it would first be converted to 231 by the code calling `pinMode`.  The end result is the same: `pinMode` and `digitalWrite` will have unpredictable behavior and could clobber random parts of memory if you call them with a bad pin argument.

Answer (score 4):

In the standard libraries, there are macros designed for converting pins to ports, which are used in assembly. Here they are for the Uno from Arduino 1.0.5:

```
#define digitalPinToPCICR(p)    (((p) >= 0 && (p) <= 21) ? (&PCICR) : ((uint8_t *)0))
#define digitalPinToPCICRbit(p) (((p) <= 7) ? 2 : (((p) <= 13) ? 0 : 1))
#define digitalPinToPCMSK(p)    (((p) <= 7) ? (&PCMSK2) : (((p) <= 13) ? (&PCMSK0) : (((p) <= 21) ? (&PCMSK1) : ((uint8_t *)0))))
#define digitalPinToPCMSKbit(p) (((p) <= 7) ? (p) : (((p) <= 13) ? ((p) - 8) : ((p) - 14)))
```

There are more, but I won't show them here.

I believe your program would subtract 14 from 999, which would still be too big for the brogram. It would then try to point to the 985th element of the `digital_pn_to_bit_mask_PGM` array, which only contains 20 elements. This would most likely end up screwing the Arduino by pointing to a random spot in progmem.